# Get Data in Ajax Response After Successful Insert Query in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to insert form data into database using ajax method and then redirect it  to next page. i have successfully passed data in ajax and inserted to database table but what i am having issue is, i want to get generated reference id in response, so i can pass that reference-id to next page to controll other form entries.
How can we do this

This is Myform Part( having two or three input for reference) with Ajax Code and where

```
<form id="visaForm" name="visaForm" action="https://www.domainurl.com/india-visa/personal-details" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="country" name="country" value="DZA"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="reference_number" name="reference_number" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="visa_type_id" name="visa_type_id" value="1">
 <input id="next" class="btn primary-btn" type="button" value="Save &amp; Continue">
</form>
<script>
$('#next').on('click',function(){
var $form = $('#visaForm');
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    //alert(serializedData);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"https://www.domainurl.com/india-visa/add-applicants",
            data: "gofor=save_data&"+serializedData,
            success:function(response){
                responsepre = response.split('~');
                document.getElementById("reference_number").value= responsepre[0];
                $('#visaForm').submit();
            }
        });
}); 

</script>
```

This is My Controller Method

```
public function add_applicants()
{
 $this->load->model('visa/Process_model');
 $this->Process_model->insertappdata(); 
}
```

This is My Model

```
function insertappdata()
{
   $query=$this->db->query("select * from appstbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   $data = $query->result_array();
   $str = $data[0]['appid'];
   $int = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '',$str);
   $pure_str = str_replace($int, "", $str);
   $appid = $pure_str.($int+147);

   $data = array(
    'phoneno' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
    'whatsappno' => $this->input->post('whatsappnumber'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email_id'),
    'portofarrival' => $this->input->post('port_of_arrival'),       
    'appid'=>$appid,        
     );               
   $this->db->insert('appstbl', $data);
}
```

What i want is to Pass Inserted "Appid" into Myview, So it will be passed on Next Controller Method On Form Action url.

Comment: There are multiple ways to pass a variable from one page to the next. GET params, localStorage, cookies. Navigating elsewhere using JS is done with `location.href = "some_relative_path"`. You are submitting the form instead, after having "submitted" it via AJAX. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Chris G : I want to get generated $appid in ajax response so i can redirect it using location.href="Path" Method. I am not able to get that in ajax.

Comment: What is the server sending back? Your ajax `success` function suggests you're getting a reply?

Comment: i have tried -  alert(response); in success. but getting 3 Square Brackets there in response. i also tested in Console it is giving me response code 200 and the data i have submitted in form. but i am not getting 'appid' there.

Comment: You need to set up codeigniter so it sends back `$appid` in the reply to the POST request.

Comment: @Chris G - Any help or Reference it will help me alot mate.

Comment: I have never really used CI but from a quick search it seems all you have to do is echo something. Try adding `echo $appid;` after your db->insert. Add `console.log(response);` in your `success` and tell us exactly what you get.

Comment: @ChrisG - I am getting Appid in Console.

Answer (score 0):

After the insert, you can use `insert_id()` to retrieve last inserted ID.

Example:

Model:

```
   $this->db->insert('appstbl', $data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   return $insert_id;
```

Controller:

```
$insert_id = $this->Process_model->insertappdata(); 
echo json_encode($insert_id); //return insert id to ajax
```

Updated: I just realised what you meant by `$appid`

Model:

```
$this->db->insert('appstbl', $data);
       return $appid;
```

Controller:

```
$appid = $this->Process_model->insertappdata(); 
echo json_encode($appid); //return insert id to ajax
```

Comment: True, but $appid is based on the `appid` column, not the row's `id`. The question is about getting that data back to the client, not about finding out the latest `id`.

Comment: Oh right. Apologies, I just realized what OP was trying to say.

Comment: @adis - i think you have added model code for controller and controller code for model. please check

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks.

Comment: How did you go?